# If a function is not called in PHP does the code still run within the function?

Tags: php

I was wondering, I have a few functions in PHP that're not called every time but still are included in my files on each load. Does it still run the code even if your not calling the function at that time? The reason I'm asking, the codes in my function are expensive to run CPU wise and I don't call them every time and want to make sure if there not called they do not run the code within the function.

Thank you

Comment: No that's the purpose of functions and function calls.

Comment: Functions will only run if called, so no need to worry :-)

Comment: How would the code run by itself? Function have arguments; what would their values be? When would the functions run? In what order? There are so many questions with difficult answers that it should be apparent.

Comment: There is technically some load time while code is parsed. However, no code is executed.

Comment: @chriz I wasn't to sure, so if you do not call them then they do not run then. Easy enough, thank you!

Comment: You can do one thing import function to import the function files then use it

Comment: The answer is simply: no.

Comment: Depends on what you mean. If you have a huge file full with functions that are not called, the file remains huge (kb). PHP does load the entire file and remember the content. PHP does not run function if these are not called. So in short, don't create huge `funcions.php` files.

Comment: @Bondye There are some cases that you might want to though.  Say for instance an Enterprise server product that manges some sort of data base.  When you have God knows how many actual applications for this server, having one standard include library for the majority of the core functions, it would be usefull to do so.

Comment: @defaultNINJA That is called Object Oriented Programming... The OP is not working OOP.

Comment: @Bondye Not true. In many cases the file MAY be an Object that is created via a custom class that stores that data and when instantiated provide access to common functions and variables. But in OOP these are typically linked to an Object, i.e. Car Object has varibles color, model, make and functions setModel, setColor, setMake. Basicly everything has to do with just the Object. Where as you could include a custom library that just provides functions to make data base connection, access password hash tables, etc. Function that are widely used, but are not related to an Object.

Comment: Tell me 1 method that is not part of an object please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, a function that isn't explicitly called does not run.  However, here is a short what and why we use functions that I found.

> A function is a "black box" that we've locked part of our program
>   into. The idea behind a function is that it compartmentalizes part of
>   the program, and in particular, that the code within the function has
>   some useful properties:
>
> 1. It performs some well-defined task, which will be useful to other
>      parts of the program.
> 2. It might be useful to other programs as well; that is, we might be
>          able to reuse it (and without having to rewrite it).
> 3. The rest of the program doesn't have to know the details of how the
>      function is implemented. This can make the rest of the program
>      easier to think about.
> 4. The function performs its task well. It may be written to do a
>      little more than is required by the first program that calls it,
>      with the anticipation that the calling program (or some other
>      program) may later need the extra functionality or improved
>      performance. (It's important that a finished function do its job
>      well, otherwise there might be a reluctance to call it, and it
>      therefore might not achieve the goal of reusability.)
> 5. By placing the code to perform the useful task into a function, and
>      simply calling the function in the other parts of the program where
>      the task must be performed, the rest of the program becomes clearer:
>      rather than having some large, complicated, difficult-to-understand
>      piece of code repeated wherever the task is being performed, we have
>      a single simple function call, and the name of the function reminds
>      us which task is being performed.
> 6. Since the rest of the program doesn't have to know the details of
>      how the function is implemented, the rest of the program doesn't
>      care if the function is reimplemented later, in some different way
>      (as long as it continues to perform its same task, of course!). This
>      means that one part of the program can be rewritten, to improve
>      performance or add a new feature (or simply to fix a bug), without
>      having to rewrite the rest of the program.
>
> Functions are probably the most important weapon in our battle against
>   software complexity. You'll want to learn when it's appropriate to
>   break processing out into functions (and also when it's not), and how
>   to set up function interfaces to best achieve the qualities mentioned
>   above: reuseability, information hiding, clarity, and maintainability.

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx5.html

Comment: TL;DR: No, uncalled functions aren't ran.

Comment: I figured given the evidence of what a functions purpose is, it would point to why it doesn't run on its own :)

Comment: Statements within a PHP function of mine were actually executed and resulting in an error, can you please help me debug? Found this answer when Googling about it.